# Push Notification issue with FCM in iOS13

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, ios13

I am using FCM for push notifications. I used to refresh the content of the app using the below method

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
```

Now with iOS13 this method is not firing anymore. I have included apns-push-type and apns-priority as well.

Comment: is 'didReceiveRegistrationToken' or 'didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken' method calling? Try to build new iPA using lastest xcode 11.

Comment: Yes. they are working fine

Comment: How do you forward your APN token to FCM? Do you rely on FCM swizzling or do you forward it manually?

Comment: Its with FCM swizzling

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the issue.

```
UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
```

this has to run for every launch. Better to keep this in didFinishLoadingWithOptions method. In my previous version, I used to call this for the first time but looks like it has to be for every launch.

and make sure set delegates for notification and messaging also.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
```

Comment: didFinishLoadingWithOptions

Comment: This literally saved my life!

Comment: Saved my life also!

Answer (score 1):

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

 if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
             // your code
             completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
        } else {

        }
}
```

- also check your APNS certificate on FCM, it must .p12 type must be available in keychain that you are using for your current XCode version